# Android emulator is very slow even after installing intel HAXM

Tags: android-emulator, emulation, haxm

my pc has 8 gb ram, intel i5-4rth gen , 2 gb nividia card.
win 7

my emulator of API 21 is very slow and laggy even after installing intel HAXM manually. 
 I have done everything that has been discussed here. please suggest me something.

Comment: would you please explain in detail.. i dont know much about these things..

Comment: Use GenyMotion: genymotion.com.

Comment: Are you sure that HAXM is working? When you launch your emulator, does the Run view (docked in Android Studio by default towards the lower-left corner) indicate that HAX is working or not working?

Comment: Don't use the emulator. Use a real device.

Comment: @CommonsWare If HAXM isn't working you can't start the emulator in Android Studio.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan: While that is the case today, I do not think that was the case over two years ago, when I made that comment. There was a period of time where if HAXM was not installed, you would be able to run the emulator, but it would be very slow.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was Avast's "Hardware assisted Virtualization". When I disabled it by going to `Avast>Settings>Troubleshooting>Uncheck "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization"` and rebooted the PC emulator became super fast and responsive.

[Uncheck "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" from Avast>Settings>Troubleshooting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIwJT.png)

Reason: Only one software can use VT-x at a time. This is the reason why we have to disable Hyper-V before using HAXM.

If you are using another anti-virus or some software that is using Hardware virtualization feature, try disabling it.

Comment: Wow amazing I would never guess that avast is causing that problem
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I`m have same issue (i5, integrated video, W10x64), and today was found a way to fix: 
add "-gpu guest" parameter to emulator.exe

Unfortunately, it should be started from a .bat file or command prompt.

Whole launch string look like

```
emulator @avd_name -accel on -gpu guest
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

After the download from the SDK manager you have to launch the IntelHAXM.exe that you can find inside the Android SDK manager folder, precisely in

extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

Comment: Nowadays there is only intelhaxm-android.exe there